# Extend Highcharts options as plugin

Tags: highcharts

I want to create a Highcharts Plugin which should improve the Accessibility module.
In the plugin code I want to change the screenReaderSectionFormatter (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/accessibility.screenReaderSectionFormatter). Can I add the function somehow to the general chart options? Or can I override the function in another way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain what exactly are you trying to do. If you want to change that option then you could set it to a different function through API - link to the API reference is in you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the highcharts function if you wish. This piece of code will add a default function for screenReaderSectionFormatter if one is not provided in the settings

```
var originalHighchartsFunction = Highcharts.chart
Highcharts.chart = function() {
   var higchartsSettings = arguments[1];

   if (higchartsSettings.accessibility == undefined) {
       higchartsSettings.accessibility = {
                screenReaderSectionFormatter: function(){
                        // your code
            }
       }
   }
   return originalHighchartsFunction.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

here is the full fiddle where i added the load event in the function override as a proof of concept http://jsfiddle.net/uz7bd7xo/1/